# How do I get the complete virtual path of an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, path, virtual

How do I know the the complete virtual path that my application is currently hosted? For example:

```
http://www.mysite.com/myApp
```

or

```
http://www.mysite.com/myApp/mySubApp
```

I know the application path of HttpRequest but it only returns the folder name that my application is currently hosted, but how do I get the initial part?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The domain name part of the path is not really a property of the application itself, but depends on the requesting URL. You might be able to reach a single Web site from many different host names. To get the domain name associated with the **current request**, along with the virtual path of the current application, you could do:

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath
```

Technically, an "application" is a virtual directory defined in IIS and `Request.ApplicationPath` returns exactly that. If you want to get the folder in which the current **request** is handled, you can do this:

```
VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(Request.Path)
```

ASP.NET has no idea how to distinguish your sub-application from a bigger application if it's not defined as a virtual directory in IIS. Without registering in IIS, it just sees the whole thing as a single app.

Comment: And if the application is a virtual directory in IIS, but the page we're requested is inside several folder, but we want path including virtual directory but not folders, how to do this?

Comment: @Krunal [HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainappvirtualpath(v=vs.110).aspx) or Request.ApplicationPath

Answer (score 18):

```
Request.Url
```

it contains several points that you might consider to use, see the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In .NET 4.5

```
    VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(path)
```

Answer (score 6):

The below code will solve the purpose, however you have to do a bit tuning for two types of scenarios:

1. Hosted as separate web application.
2. Hosted as Virtual application within a web application.

   HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;

Answer (score 2):

Try this (Haven't tried it)

```
public string GetVirtualPath(string physicalPath)
{
string rootpath = Server.MapPath("~/");
physicalPath = physicalPath.Replace(rootpath, "");
physicalPath = physicalPath.Replace("\\", "/");
return "~/" + physicalPath;
}
```

[Link 1](http://weblogs.asp.net/pleloup/archive/2004/06/24/164706.aspx)

[Link 2](http://www.teknowmagic.net/GetTip.aspx?tip=6)

Answer (score 0):

**`Url.Content("~")`** worked great for me and is nice and simple.  I used it in the view like this:

```
<a href="@(Url.Content("~" + attachment))">
```

Here my `attachment` is a path like *"/Content/Documents/Blah.PDF"*.

When my app is published to a IIS site that uses a virtual directory, `Url.Content("~")` resolves to just the virtual directory name like, *"/app-test"*, for example.