# ASP.net MVC application URL in JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have hosted an MVC application on my IIS under default website. So I can access the application by browsing to `http://localhost/appname`.

I also have a URL rewrite module which returns the same homepage if the URL entered is like this 
`http://localhost/appname/request/*`

I would like to get the path url (`http://localhost/appname/`)in my index.html file. I am using razor syntax. So in case I host the site under a different path or different appname, my ajax queries and css won't be affected.

How do I get the `http://localhost/appname` in index.html file's javascript.

Comment: RequestContext..ApplicationPath for razor , window.location.hostname for host name

Answer (score 4):

You can't access the full application path (ie. `www.hostname.com/appname/`) in JavaScript as it has no knowledge of the server-side implementation, it's just a URL to JavaScript.

You could inject the app path into your page somewhere using `@Url.Content("~/...")`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var appPath = @Url.Content("~/");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/main.js")"></script>
```

In the above, `main.js` will be able to access the `appPath` variable.

Comment: I used that and I get `appPath = http://hostname/appname/request/`. Basically @Url.Content will give you whatever request server received from the client. It won't send you app path.

Comment: I will try to use RequestContext.ApplicationPath. And you are right, this is a server side implementation.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var base = "@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)";
 var path = "@Request.ApplicationPath";
 var baseURL = base + path + "/";
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932745/how-do-i-get-the-complete-virtual-path-of-an-asp-net-application)