# How to get ASP .net web application's virtual path?

Tags: asp.net

I have a page `http://localhost:65248/ZeroLabs/msg_preview.aspx`.

I want to get `http://localhost:65248/ZeroLabs` part.

My code runs in this page `Page_Load` event.

I didn't find anything good in `Request.Url`.

[image]

Currently I use this:

```
//http + :// + localhost:65248 + /ZeroLabs
string omg_wtf = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath;
```

I feel this isn't a way how I supposed to get what I want.
Any less ugly way, please?

Comment: Well, is `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(0, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.LastIndexOf("/"))` any less "ugly"? Please define "ugly" in an objective, non-opinionated way.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Well... I hoped for some single property... but your way is less ugly too... Or maybe no if we have something like that `?asd=qwe/sdf`... Or maybe yes if we can't have something like that in AbsoluteUri...

Comment: Curious why you want it. Generally you can just use tilde to construct paths to resources. There's a bunch of ways to get the full path though [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853294/how-do-i-get-the-site-root-url)

Comment: @Nikki9696 - I use it to concatenate with other page names in code. For example I build an list of *.aspx pages stored in physical path (`string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.aspx")`) corresponding to `http://localhost:65248/ZeroLabs` and give it to user, so he can visit them. It's like `http://localhost:65248/ZeroLabs` + `/` + paths[i].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, as it's a long time using web pages with Asp.Net web forms. But If I recall correctly, you just need to use ~ for getting the virtual path of you web application/website.

So `~/ZeroLabs` should work for you. Just give it a try.

Also see this [link on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932745/how-do-i-get-the-complete-virtual-path-of-an-asp-net-application). It might be useful.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I found `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;` there. Still not a single property, yet this this better than my junk code.